# Remove Excel data link in Visio Drawing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-visio-2010

I am creating a server topology for one of our SharePoint farms and thought it would be easy to just link the Excel spreadsheet with our server information to the Visio drawing to auto-populate some things. It didn't work out that well, but the drawing is finished without it now. 
I cannot remove the link between the Excel spreadsheet and the Visio diagram. Whenever the drawing is opened the linked excel server list opens in a pane at the very bottom of the window. How would I eliminate the data link? Or just the spreadsheet from view when being opened?

Comment: Have a look at this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829224 which may get help you.

Answer (score 5):

Found it just to un-linking any reference to the data source, right-clicking the data source pane and choosing Remove Data Source Link.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click in the data grid and click Data Sources > Remove Link.
Note:  If you right click the frame and not the content of the box, the option does not appear.